# Faster way to see if an array contains values besides the one specified

Tags: php

I have an array where each element has a subarray with multiple Ids.  When looping through the array, I'd like to check if the subarray has any elements besides a given one.

For example, I'd like to echo 'Yes' whenever one of the subarrays has any ids other than 'TESTID'.

I can do this by looping through the subarray, but I'd like to know of a way that doesn't require double loops.

Here's the current code:

```
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    ...

    if (besidesInArray('TESTID',$element['ids'])) {
        //operations
    } else {
        //element only has 'TESTID'
    }

...
}
...

function besidesInArray($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $hay) {
        if($hay != $needle) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

While this code works, I'd like to see if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: Post your code as it stands. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Get all the array keys and then do array intersect, check http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`in_array()`**](https://www.php.net/in_array) function to achieve this

```
foreach($array as $key => $subarray)
{
    if(in_array("TESTID", $subarray))
    {
        //found
    } else {
       //not found
    }
}
```

Comment: Except they want to find if there are OTHERS that are not TESTID.

Comment: There is an else that can handle what he requested, this was just to give op a general view about the function and how to work it out

Comment: No, the else is fired when TESTID is NOT found, not when OTHERS ARE found

Comment: He's not looking for `others` literaly but for other results as he said `"subarrays has any ids other than 'TESTID'."`

Comment: Exactly.  If `$subarray` contains `['TESTID', 'FOOID']` then the else does not fire. Which is not what OP stated.  Other in this case is 'FOOID'

Comment: Why shouldn't it fire? -.-"

Comment: Because 'TESTID' is found:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a5b09dec475c447361d41d974d6b62ef62b36064

Answer (score 0):

`preg_grep` for `TESTID` but invert the grep so that it returns entries NOT matching.

```
foreach($array as $subarray) {
    if(preg_grep("/TESTID/", $subarray, PREG_GREP_INVERT)) {
        echo 'Yes'; //others found
    }
}
```

`TESTID` could be a var instead.  Man I love some `preg_grep`!

Answer (score -1):

```
  find = implode(')|(',$mypatternarray);
   find.="(".find.")";

foreach($subarray as $subar){
        if(preg_match("find",$subar)>0)){
        echo "id found";
        }

}
```